# Cannot find sub-directories

Tags: matlab, directory, pattern-matching, filepath, subdirectory

I'm trying to identify a certain subdirectory pattern in my script. The issue I'm getting is that the directories are not being Identified correctly.
Here is my current code:

```matlab
parentDir = '/data/home1/fL/user/path/to/subdirectories/'
totalFiles = subdir(fullfile(parentDir, '/*.7'));

name = {totalFiles.name}' % cells containing directories with the .7 ext this is a 118*1 cell
numTotalFiles=length(name); % =118

% this section is supposed to sort through all the subdirectories paths that
% have the pattern A_G/*.7 and p_G/*7 in their pathname but fails to do so. 

for i=1:numTotalFiles
  patternsplit = totalFiles(i).name
  str = ["*/A_G/*.7","*/p_G/*.7"]
  ptrn = ["A_G","p_G"]
  pattern = patternsplit(startsWith(str,ptrn))
  found = pattern
end
```

I expect the output to be a list of subdirectories containing the patterns `A_G/*.7` and `p_G/*.7`. I'm thinking this may be a 44x1 cell containing all the subdirectories names with these patterns.

Comment: Welcome!

To get it correctly: You're looking for folders that are either named `A_G` or `p_G` in your parent folder (recursive) and contain at least one `*.7` file? What does `subdir` do? My Matlab (2019a) does not know this function.

Comment: I'm looking for folders that have either the name A_G or p_G and must end with a *.7 file in both instances, and subdir is a recursive file search I downloaded from the file exchange sorry dir did not list my parent path correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "must end with a *.7 file" the last (which ordering scheme applied) file in the folder must be a `*.7` file or the folders should contain at least one?

Comment: both of the the filepaths should contain at least one *.7 ext. the *.7 is the file will be used in later code so path should be like: '/data/home1/fL/user/path/to/subdirectories/**/A_G/*.7'

Comment: Since `.7` is a valid file name, again: Are you looking for `**/A_G/.7` or `**/A_G/something.7`?

Comment: Oh Sorry! the second one **/A_G/something.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses another approach than your previous one, which first listed all filenames and than tried to find matching patterns in the list.

This approach uses recursion (this task calls for recursion, in my opinion). The major work is made a function that scans the content of the current directory for `.7` files. If the current directory's name is either `A_G` or `p_G`, it returns the file names. Then, it calls itself with the subdirectories.

**Note that this code generates some files and directories for testing!**

```
% Let's create a directory structure with some files with extension .7

mkdir ('foo/bar/baz/A_G');
mkfile('foo/bar/baz/A_G', 1);
mkdir ('foo/bar/baz/p_G');
mkfile('foo/bar/baz/p_G', 2);

mkdir ('foo/bar/baz/test');
mkfile('foo/bar/baz/test', 99); % should not be found since in directory `test`


mkdir ('foo/bar/p_G');
mkfile('foo/bar/p_G', 3);
mkdir ('foo/bar/A_G');
mkfile('foo/bar/A_G', 4);

mkdir ('foo/p_G');
mkfile('foo/p_G', 5);
mkfile('foo/p_G', 6);


% Here it starts

parent = '.'; % My parent folder is my current folder

l_find_files(parent, false)


function mkfile(d, n)
% just a helper function to generate a file named `<n>.7` in the dirctory <d> 
    fid = fopen(sprintf('%s%s%d.7',d,filesep,n),'w');
    fclose(fid);
end


function res = l_find_files(d, is_candidate)
% recursively scans a directory <d> for *.7 files.
% if is_candidate == true, returns them.
% is_candidate should be set to true if the name of the directory is one of
% {'A_G', 'p_G'}


    files = dir(d);
    res = {};
    if is_candidate
        % get files with extension .7
        % 
        % Instead of using the above `files`, I rescan the directory. Using
        % `files` instead might be faster

        ext7 = dir(fullfile(d,'*.7'));

        res = arrayfun(@(x)fullfile(d, x.name), ext7, 'UniformOutput', false);
    end

    % get the indices of the subdirectories
    issub = [files(:).isdir];
    subdirs = {files(issub).name};

    % call this function for the subdirectories
    for sd = subdirs
        if ~any(strcmp(sd{1}, {'.', '..'})) % omit . and ..
            result = l_find_files(fullfile(d, sd{1}), any(strcmp(sd{1}, {'A_G', 'p_G'})));
            res = [res(:)' result(:)'];
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Awesome it worked!! Thank you so much for the help!